# Assign pandas dataframe column dtypes

Tags: python, pandas

I want to set the `dtype`s of multiple columns in `pd.Dataframe` (I have a file that I've had to manually parse into a list of lists, as the file was not amenable for `pd.read_csv`)

```
import pandas as pd
print pd.DataFrame([['a','1'],['b','2']],
                   dtype={'x':'object','y':'int'},
                   columns=['x','y'])
```

I get

```
ValueError: entry not a 2- or 3- tuple
```

The only way I can set them is by looping through each column variable and recasting with `astype`.

```
dtypes = {'x':'object','y':'int'}
mydata = pd.DataFrame([['a','1'],['b','2']],
                      columns=['x','y'])
for c in mydata.columns:
    mydata[c] = mydata[c].astype(dtypes[c])
print mydata['y'].dtype   #=> int64
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: This would perhaps be a good [bug / feature request](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/new), currently I'm not sure what dtype arg is doing (you can pass it a scalar, but it's not strict)...

Comment: FYI: `df = pd.DataFrame([['a','1'],['b','2']], dtype='int', columns=['x','y'])` "works"... but :s

Comment: Yeah, "works" indeed; unpredictably...

Comment: This GitHub issue may soon become relevant: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/9287

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Since 0.17, you have to use the explicit conversions:

```
pd.to_datetime, pd.to_timedelta and pd.to_numeric
```

(As mentioned below, no more "magic", `convert_objects` has been deprecated in 0.17)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': {0: 'a', 1: 'b'}, 'y': {0: '1', 1: '2'}, 'z': {0: '2018-05-01', 1: '2018-05-02'}})

df.dtypes

x    object
y    object
z    object
dtype: object

df

   x  y           z
0  a  1  2018-05-01
1  b  2  2018-05-02
```

You can apply these to each column you want to convert:

```
df["y"] = pd.to_numeric(df["y"])
df["z"] = pd.to_datetime(df["z"])    
df

   x  y          z
0  a  1 2018-05-01
1  b  2 2018-05-02

df.dtypes

x            object
y             int64
z    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

and confirm the dtype is updated.

---

OLD/DEPRECATED ANSWER for pandas 0.12 - 0.16: You can use [`convert_objects`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.convert_objects.html) to infer better dtypes:

```
In [21]: df
Out[21]: 
   x  y
0  a  1
1  b  2

In [22]: df.dtypes
Out[22]: 
x    object
y    object
dtype: object

In [23]: df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
Out[23]: 
   x  y
0  a  1
1  b  2

In [24]: df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True).dtypes
Out[24]: 
x    object
y     int64
dtype: object
```

*Magic!* (Sad to see it deprecated.)

Comment: like `type.convert` in R a little bit; nice but does leave one wishing for explicit specifications in some cases.

Comment: @crippledlambda agreed, I think this would be a good feature request and not too difficultTM to implement.

Comment: Be careful if you have a column that needs to be a string but contains at least one value that could be converted to an int. All it takes is one value and the entire field is converted to float64

Comment: @MichaelDavidWatson wow, that sounds like a bug. Could you post a new issue on github: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/

Comment: We have a discussion going about it here: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/9589

Comment: I noticed `convert_objects()` has been deprecated... i'm not sure what replaced it?

Comment: To re-infer data dtypes for object columns, use DataFrame.infer_objects()

Comment: Please delete or edit this answer, it's obsolete. `convert_objects` has been deprecated since 0.17 (2017) in favor of data-type specific converters `pd.to_datetime, to_timedelta, to_numeric`

Comment: @smci okay, I've edited. There's a bunch of deprecated answers, I need to work out a way to find them all.

Comment: There is now (2021) [`convert_dtypes()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.convert_dtypes.html#pandas.DataFrame.convert_dtypes) and [`infer_objects()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.infer_objects.html) available.

Answer (score 78):

you can set the types explicitly with pandas `DataFrame.astype(dtype, copy=True, raise_on_error=True, **kwargs)` and pass in a dictionary with the dtypes you want to `dtype`

here's an example:

```
import pandas as pd
wheel_number = 5
car_name = 'jeep'
minutes_spent = 4.5

# set the columns
data_columns = ['wheel_number', 'car_name', 'minutes_spent']

# create an empty dataframe
data_df = pd.DataFrame(columns = data_columns)
df_temp = pd.DataFrame([[wheel_number, car_name, minutes_spent]],columns = data_columns)
data_df = data_df.append(df_temp, ignore_index=True)
```

you get

```
In [11]: data_df.dtypes
Out[11]:
wheel_number     float64
car_name          object
minutes_spent    float64
dtype: object
```

with

```
data_df = data_df.astype(dtype= {"wheel_number":"int64",
        "car_name":"object","minutes_spent":"float64"})
```

now you can see that it's changed

```
In [18]: data_df.dtypes
Out[18]:
wheel_number       int64
car_name          object
minutes_spent    float64
```

Comment: That's the best way to pass the entire dictionary defined by the "dtypes" of another dataframe to the new one. Thanks!

Comment: This is great! Equivalent to being able to pass in the schema during read_csv construction.

Answer (score 71):

For those coming from Google (etc.) such as myself:

[`convert_objects`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.convert_objects.html) has been deprecated since 0.17 - if you use it, you get a warning like this one:

```
FutureWarning: convert_objects is deprecated.  Use the data-type specific converters 
pd.to_datetime, pd.to_timedelta and pd.to_numeric.
```

You should do something like the following:

- `df =`[`df.astype(np.float)`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html)
- `df["A"] =`[`pd.to_numeric(df["A"])`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html)

Comment: If you threw in some examples of `pd.to_datetime, to_timedelta, to_numeric` this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 20):

Another way to set the column types is to first construct a numpy record array with your desired types, fill it out and then pass it to a DataFrame constructor.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np    

x = np.empty((10,), dtype=[('x', np.uint8), ('y', np.float64)])
df = pd.DataFrame(x)

df.dtypes ->

x      uint8
y    float64
```

Answer (score 7):

You're better off using typed np.arrays, and then pass the data and column names as a dictionary.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
# Feature: np arrays are 1: efficient, 2: can be pre-sized
x = np.array(['a', 'b'], dtype=object)
y = np.array([ 1 ,  2 ], dtype=np.int32)
df = pd.DataFrame({
   'x' : x,    # Feature: column name is near data array
   'y' : y,
   }
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([['a', '1'], ['b', '2']], columns=['x', 'y'])
# Cast a pandas object to a specified dtype
df = df.astype({'x': 'object', 'y': int})
# Check
print(df.dtypes)
```

Comment: Your answer only contains code. I recommend that you don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score -1):

facing similar problem to you. In my case I have 1000's of files from cisco logs that I need to parse manually.

In order to be flexible with fields and types I have successfully tested using StringIO + read_cvs which indeed does accept a dict for the dtype specification.

I usually get each of the files  ( 5k-20k lines) into a buffer and create the dtype dictionaries dynamically.

Eventually I concatenate ( with categorical... thanks to 0.19)  these dataframes into a large data frame that I dump into hdf5.

Something along these lines

```
import pandas as pd
import io 

output = io.StringIO()
output.write('A,1,20,31\n')
output.write('B,2,21,32\n')
output.write('C,3,22,33\n')
output.write('D,4,23,34\n')

output.seek(0)


df=pd.read_csv(output, header=None,
        names=["A","B","C","D"],
        dtype={"A":"category","B":"float32","C":"int32","D":"float64"},
        sep=","
       )

df.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 5 entries, 0 to 4
Data columns (total 4 columns):
A    5 non-null category
B    5 non-null float32
C    5 non-null int32
D    5 non-null float64
dtypes: category(1), float32(1), float64(1), int32(1)
memory usage: 205.0 bytes
None
```

Not very pythonic.... but does the job

Hope it helps.

JC