# what are all the dtypes that pandas recognizes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

For pandas, would anyone know, if any datatype apart from

(i) `float64`, `int64`  (and other variants of `np.number` like `float32`, `int8` etc.)

(ii)  `bool`

(iii) `datetime64`, `timedelta64`

such as string columns, always have a `dtype` of `object` ?

Alternatively, I want to know, if there are any datatype apart from (i), (ii) and (iii) in the list above that `pandas` does not make it's `dtype` an `object`?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21197774/assign-pandas-dataframe-column-dtypes

Comment: Since recently, also `category`: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html and http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#dtypes

Answer (score 56, accepted):

**EDIT Feb 2020 following pandas 1.0.0 release**

Pandas mostly uses NumPy arrays and dtypes for each Series (a dataframe is a collection of Series, each which can have its own dtype).  NumPy's documentation further explains [dtype](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.html#numpy.dtype), [data types](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html), and [data type objects](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html#arrays-dtypes). In addition, the answer provided by @lcameron05 provides an excellent description of the numpy dtypes. Furthermore, the pandas docs on [dtypes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/basics.html?highlight=basics#dtypes) have a lot of additional information.

> The main types stored in pandas objects are float, int, bool,
> datetime64[ns], timedelta[ns], and object. In addition these dtypes
> have item sizes, e.g. int64 and int32.

> By default integer types are int64 and float types are float64,
> REGARDLESS of platform (32-bit or 64-bit). The following will all
> result in int64 dtypes.
>
> Numpy, however will choose platform-dependent types when creating
> arrays. The following WILL result in int32 on 32-bit platform.
> One of the major changes to version 1.0.0 of pandas is the introduction of `pd.NA` to represent scalar missing values (rather than the previous values of `np.nan`, `pd.NaT` or `None`, depending on usage).

Pandas extends NumPy's type system and also allows users to write their on [extension types](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/development/extending.html#extending-extension-types). The following lists all of pandas extension types.

[**1) Time zone handling**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#timeseries-timezone)

Kind of data: tz-aware datetime (note that NumPy does not support timezone-aware datetimes).

Data type: [DatetimeTZDtype](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeTZDtype.html#pandas.DatetimeTZDtype)

Scalar: [Timestamp](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.html#pandas.Timestamp)

Array: [arrays.DatetimeArray](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.arrays.DatetimeArray.html#pandas.arrays.DatetimeArray)

String Aliases: 'datetime64[ns, ]'

[**2) Categorical data**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html#categorical)

Kind of data: Categorical

Data type: [CategoricalDtype](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.CategoricalDtype.html#pandas.CategoricalDtype)

Scalar: (none)

Array: [Categorical](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.html#pandas.Categorical)

String Aliases: 'category'

[**3) Time span representation**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#timeseries-periods)

Kind of data: period (time spans)

Data type: [PeriodDtype](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.PeriodDtype.html#pandas.PeriodDtype)

Scalar: [Period](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Period.html#pandas.Period)

Array: [arrays.PeriodArray](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.arrays.PeriodArray.html#pandas.arrays.PeriodArray)

String Aliases: 'period[]', 'Period[]'

[**4) Sparse data structures**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/sparse.html#sparse)

Kind of data: sparse

Data type: [SparseDtype](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.SparseDtype.html#pandas.SparseDtype)

Scalar: (none)

Array: [arrays.SparseArray](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.arrays.SparseArray.html#pandas.arrays.SparseArray)

String Aliases: 'Sparse', 'Sparse[int]', 'Sparse[float]'

[**5) IntervalIndex**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html#advanced-intervalindex)

Kind of data: intervals

Data type: [IntervalDtype](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.IntervalDtype.html#pandas.IntervalDtype)

Scalar: [Interval](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Interval.html#pandas.Interval)

Array: [arrays.IntervalArray](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.arrays.IntervalArray.html#pandas.arrays.IntervalArray)

String Aliases: 'interval', 'Interval', 'Interval[<numpy_dtype>]', 'Interval[datetime64[ns, ]]', 'Interval[timedelta64[]]'

[**6) Nullable integer data type**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html#integer-na)

Kind of data: nullable integer

Data type: [Int64Dtype](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Int64Dtype.html#pandas.Int64Dtype), ...

Scalar: (none)

Array: [arrays.IntegerArray](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.arrays.IntegerArray.html#pandas.arrays.IntegerArray)

String Aliases: 'Int8', 'Int16', 'Int32', 'Int64', 'UInt8', 'UInt16', 'UInt32', 'UInt64'

[**7) Working with text data**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html#text)

Kind of data: Strings

Data type: [StringDtype](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.StringDtype.html#pandas.StringDtype)

Scalar: [str](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str)

Array: [arrays.StringArray](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.arrays.StringArray.html#pandas.arrays.StringArray)

String Aliases: 'string'

[**8) Boolean data with missing values**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/arrays.html#api-arrays-bool)

Kind of data: Boolean (with NA)

Data type: [BooleanDtype](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.BooleanDtype.html#pandas.BooleanDtype)

Scalar: [bool](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bool)

Array:  [arrays.BooleanArray](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.arrays.BooleanArray.html#pandas.arrays.BooleanArray)

String Aliases: 'boolean'

Answer (score 67):

`pandas` borrows its dtypes from `numpy`. For demonstration of this see the following:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,'C',2.]})
df['A'].dtype

>>> dtype('O')

type(df['A'].dtype)

>>> numpy.dtype
```

You can find the list of valid `numpy.dtypes` [in the documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html):

> '?'   boolean
>
> 'b'   (signed) byte
>
> 'B'   unsigned byte
>
> 'i'   (signed) integer
>
> 'u'   unsigned integer
>
> 'f'   floating-point
>
> 'c'   complex-floating point
>
> 'm'   timedelta
>
> 'M'   datetime
>
> 'O'   (Python) objects
>
> 'S', 'a'  zero-terminated bytes (not recommended)
>
> 'U'   Unicode string
>
> 'V'   raw data (void)

`pandas` should support these types. Using the `astype` method of a `pandas.Series` object with any of the above options as the input argument will result in `pandas` trying to convert the `Series` to that type (or at the very least falling back to `object` type); `'u'` is the only one that I see `pandas` not understanding at all:

```
df['A'].astype('u')

>>> TypeError: data type "u" not understood
```

This is a `numpy` error that results because the `'u'` needs to be followed by a number specifying the number of bytes per item in (which needs to be valid):

```
import numpy as np

np.dtype('u')

>>> TypeError: data type "u" not understood

np.dtype('u1')

>>> dtype('uint8')

np.dtype('u2')

>>> dtype('uint16')

np.dtype('u4')

>>> dtype('uint32')

np.dtype('u8')

>>> dtype('uint64')

# testing another invalid argument
np.dtype('u3')

>>> TypeError: data type "u3" not understood
```

To summarise, the `astype` methods of `pandas` objects will try and do something sensible with any argument that is valid for `numpy.dtype`. Note that `numpy.dtype('f')` is the same as `numpy.dtype('float32')` and `numpy.dtype('f8')` is the same as `numpy.dtype('float64')` etc. Same goes for passing the arguments to `pandas` `astype` methods.

To locate the respective data type classes in NumPy, the [Pandas docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#selecting-columns-based-on-dtype) recommends this:

```
def subdtypes(dtype):
    subs = dtype.__subclasses__()
    if not subs:
        return dtype
    return [dtype, [subdtypes(dt) for dt in subs]]

subdtypes(np.generic)
```

Output:

```
[numpy.generic,
 [[numpy.number,
   [[numpy.integer,
     [[numpy.signedinteger,
       [numpy.int8,
        numpy.int16,
        numpy.int32,
        numpy.int64,
        numpy.int64,
        numpy.timedelta64]],
      [numpy.unsignedinteger,
       [numpy.uint8,
        numpy.uint16,
        numpy.uint32,
        numpy.uint64,
        numpy.uint64]]]],
    [numpy.inexact,
     [[numpy.floating,
       [numpy.float16, numpy.float32, numpy.float64, numpy.float128]],
      [numpy.complexfloating,
       [numpy.complex64, numpy.complex128, numpy.complex256]]]]]],
  [numpy.flexible,
   [[numpy.character, [numpy.bytes_, numpy.str_]],
    [numpy.void, [numpy.record]]]],
  numpy.bool_,
  numpy.datetime64,
  numpy.object_]]
```

Pandas accepts these classes as valid types. For example, `dtype={'A': np.float}`.

NumPy docs [contain](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.scalars.html) more details and a chart:

[image: dtypes]

Answer (score 3):

Building on other answers, pandas also includes a number of its own dtypes.

> Pandas and third-party libraries extend NumPy’s type system in a few
> places. This section describes the extensions pandas has made
> internally. See Extension types for how to write your own extension
> that works with pandas. See Extension data types for a list of
> third-party libraries that have implemented an extension.
>
> The following table lists all of pandas extension types. See the
> respective document

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/basics.html#basics-dtypes

--Updated link--

Also, as of pandas 1.0 it has its own string dtype and nullable dtypes.