# Detecting a list type in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way to see if a field is an array in `pandas`? For example:

```
>>> data=[{'name':'tom','colors':[1,2,3]}]
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data)
      colors name
0  [1, 2, 3]  tom
>>> df['colors']['dtype']
Name: colors, dtype: object
```

Is there a way I can get the value `list`? Or do I need to do an `ast.literal_eval()` ? The below seems pretty crude:

```
>>> type(ast.literal_eval(str(pd.DataFrame(data)['colors'][0])))
<class 'list'>
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29245848/what-are-all-the-dtypes-that-pandas-recognizes) might be useful. Seems `list` isn't one of the data types; it just falls under `object`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the data in the columns is consistent that is lists then use:

```
type(df.loc[0,'colors'])

list
```

Comment: oh, got it, that makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: Or without `.loc`: `type(df['colors'][0])`