# Pandas: how do I select the columns of a dataframe that are of type list?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe which some columns are of type `list`. All my columns are of the same type (or all elements are a list or not). How do I select just these columns?

If I get the `dtypes` they all are of object type:

```
In [44]: df = pd.DataFrame([['a', [1,2]], ['b', [3,4]]], columns=['x', 'y'])

In [45]: df
Out[45]: 
   x       y
0  a  [1, 2]
1  b  [3, 4]

In [46]: df.dtypes
Out[46]: 
x    object
y    object
dtype: object
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29245848/what-are-all-the-dtypes-that-pandas-recognizes#:~:text=The%20main%20types%20stored%20in,bit%20or%2064%2Dbit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got an ugly way to do it:

```
df.loc[:, [name for name, typ in df.iloc[0].map(type).items() if typ==list]]
```

The result is:

```
Out[66]: 
        y
0  [1, 2]
1  [3, 4]
```

I'd accept a more elegant answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own function that designates whether or not a column contains all lists:

```
def all_lists(array):
    return all(isinstance(x, list) for x in array)

list_types = df.apply(all_lists)

print(list_types)
x    False
y     True
dtype: bool
```

Then to subset our data using the `list_types` Series:

```
list_type_subset = df.loc[:, list_types]

print(list_type_subset)
        y
0  [1, 2]
1  [3, 4]
```

Some important notes:

- If you have a huge dataframe checking if each value is a list object can be time consuming, since we're iterating over each value and checking by hand.
- `list` is not an actual `dtype`- the `"object"` dtype is essentially a catchall used by pandas when the `dtype` is not a number, boolean, datetime, or other official `dtype`. This is why we have to do things in a slightly roundabout way.