# Ho to convert a column of object type to HexaDecimal

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Assume the below dataframe is having column "num" of 'object' type

```
   num
0   0x11
1   0x3
2   0x05
3   0x4
4   0x1a
5   0x1d
6   0x82
```

The output of "print(df.dtypes)" is as:

Output:

```
 num       object
```

How to convert this object type column to Hex?

Expected Output: The output should be the same as the above mentioned 'df'. the type of the column 'num' should be changed to HEX.

I tried the below steps but not working:

```
df['num'] = [str(i) for i in df['num']]
df['num'] = [int(i,16) for i in df['num']]
df['num'] = [hex(i) for i in df['num']]
```

Comment: Can you share your expected output?

Comment: Expectation is that the 'num' column type should be change to Hex.
everything else should be the same

Comment: column type to hex??  these are all the available  column types https://stackoverflow.com/a/29246498/6660373
I never saw hex type column.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`df.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
In [391]: df['num'] = df['num'].apply(int, base=0)

In [392]: df
Out[392]: 
   num
0   17
1    3
2    5
3    4
4   26
5   29
6  130
```

Comment: I like this one.

Comment: I didn't know we can define like this also +1

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apply`:

```
df['num'] = df['num'].apply(lambda x: int(x, 16))
```

---

**df:**

```
    num
0   17
1   3
2   5
3   4
4   26
5   29
6   130
```

Answer (score 1):

#### `literal_eval`

```
from ast import literal_eval

df['num'] = df.num.map(literal_eval)

df

   num
0   17
1    3
2    5
3    4
4   26
5   29
6  130
```

Comment: I like this one because it uses map :)