# Sum of dataframe columns to another dataframe column Python gives NaN

Tags: python, dataframe

I want to sumarize rows and columns of dataframe (`pdf` and `wdf`) and save results in another dataframe columns (`to_hex`).
I tried it for one dataframe and it worked. It doesn't work for another (it gives NaN). I cannot understand what is the difference.

```
to_hex = pd.DataFrame(0, index=np.arange(len(sasiedztwo)), columns=['ID','podroze','p_rozmyte'])
to_hex.loc[:,'ID']= wdf.index+1
to_hex.index=pdf.index
to_hex.loc[:,'podroze']= pd.DataFrame(pdf.sum(axis=0))[:]
to_hex.index=wdf.index
to_hex.loc[:,'p_rozmyte']= pd.DataFrame(wdf.sum(axis=0))[:]
```

This is how  `pdf` dataframe looks like:

```
   0  1   2  3  4  5  6  7     8
0  0  0  10  0  0  0  0  0   100
1  0  0   0  0  0  0  0  0     0
2  0  0   0  0  0  0  0  0     0
3  0  0   0  0  0  0  0  0     0
4  0  0   0  0  0  0  0  0     0
5  0  0   0  0  0  0  0  0     0
6  0  0   0  0  0  0  0  0     0
7  0  0   0  0  0  0  0  0  1000
8  0  0   0  0  0  0  0  0     0
```

This is  `wdf`:

```
    0    1      2    3      4      5      6      7       8
0  2.5  5.0   35.0  0.0   27.5   55.0   25.0   50.0   102.5
1  0.0  0.0    5.0  0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0   300.0
2  0.0  0.0    2.5  0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    25.0
3  0.0  0.0    5.0  0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0   300.0
4  0.0  0.0    2.5  0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0   525.0
5  0.0  0.0    0.0  0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0   250.0
6  0.0  0.0    2.5  0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0   525.0
7  0.0  0.0  250.0  0.0  250.0  500.0  250.0  500.0  1000.0
8  0.0  0.0    0.0  0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0   500.0
```

And this is the result in  `to_hex`:

```
  ID  podroze  p_rozmyte
0   1        0        NaN
1   2        0        NaN
2   3       10        NaN
3   4        0        NaN
4   5        0        NaN
5   6        0        NaN
6   7        0        NaN
7   8        0        NaN
8   9     1100        NaN
```

Comment: Could you add sample data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**
One option to solve it is to modify your code as follows:

```
to_hex.loc[:,'ID']= wdf.index+1
# to_hex.index=pdf.index                   # no need
to_hex.loc[:,'podroze']= pdf.sum(axis=0)   # modified; directly use the series output from SUM()
# to_hex.index=wdf.index                   # no need
to_hex.loc[:,'p_rozmyte']= wdf.sum(axis=0) # modified
```

Then you get:

```
    ID  podroze p_rozmyte
0   1   0        2.5
1   2   0        5.0
2   3   10       302.5
3   4   0        0.0
4   5   0        277.5
5   6   0        555.0
6   7   0        275.0
7   8   0        550.0
8   9   1100     3527.5
```

I think the reason that you get NaN for one case and correct values for the other case lies in `to_hex.dtypes`:

```
ID           int64
podroze      int64
p_rozmyte    int64
dtype: object
```

And as you see `to_hex` dataframe has column types as int64. This is fine when you add `pdf` dataframe (since it has the same dtype)

```
pd.DataFrame(pdf.sum(axis=0))[:].dtypes
0    int64
dtype: object
```

but does not work when you add `wdf`:

```
pd.DataFrame(wdf.sum(axis=0))[:].dtypes
0    float64
dtype: object
```

Comment: Yes, I think that is the reason... How can I change type of to_hex['podroze'] to float?

Comment: check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21197774/assign-pandas-dataframe-column-dtypes)

Comment: Works, thank you. It still doesn't for more complex data which probably means that I'm doing some data-dependend mistake.