# dtype definition for pandas dataframe with columns of VARCHAR or String

Tags: pandas, sqlalchemy, dtype

I want to get some data in a dictionary that need to go into a pandas dataframe.
The dataframe is later written in a PostgreSQL table using sqlalchemy, and I would like to get the right column types.

Hence, I specify the dtypes for the dataframe

```
dtypes = {"forretningshændelse": sqlalchemy.types.String(length=8),
     "forretningsområde": sqlalchemy.types.String(length=40), 
     "forretningsproces": sqlalchemy.types.INTEGER(), 
     "id_namespace": sqlalchemy.types.String(length=100), 
     "id_lokalId": sqlalchemy.types.String(length=36),
     "kommunekode": sqlalchemy.types.INTEGER(), 
     "registreringFra": sqlalchemy.types.DateTime()}
```

Later I use `df = pd.DataFrame(item_lst, dtype=dtypes)`, where item_lst is a list of dictionaries.

Independent from me using either `String(8)`, `String(length=8)` or `VARCHAR(8)` in the dtype definition, the result of `pd.DataFrame(item_lst, dtype=dtypes)` is always *object of type '(String or VARCHAR)' has no len()*.

How do I have to define the dtype to overcome this error?

Comment: Try letting pandas infer the data types when the DataFrame is created (just `df = pd.DataFrame(item_lst)`) and then use your `dtypes` dict with `to_sql()` when you push your DataFrame to the database, like [this](https://pastebin.com/HtNjL0RC).

Comment: Thanks @GordThompson that was the solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of forcing data types when the DataFrame is created, let pandas infer the data types (just `df = pd.DataFrame(item_lst)`) and then use your `dtypes` dict with `to_sql()` when you push your DataFrame to the database, like this:

```py
from pprint import pprint

import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("sqlite://")

item_lst = [{"forretningshændelse": "foo"}]
df = pd.DataFrame(item_lst)
print(df.info())
"""
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 1 entries, 0 to 0
Data columns (total 1 columns):
 #   Column               Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------               --------------  ----- 
 0   forretningshændelse  1 non-null      object
dtypes: object(1)
memory usage: 136.0+ bytes
None
"""

dtypes = {"forretningshændelse": sqlalchemy.types.String(length=8)}
df.to_sql("tbl", engine, index=False, dtype=dtypes)

insp = sqlalchemy.inspect(engine)
pprint(insp.get_columns("tbl"))
"""
[{'autoincrement': 'auto',
  'default': None,
  'name': 'forretningshændelse',
  'nullable': True,
  'primary_key': 0,
  'type': VARCHAR(length=8)}]
"""
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are confusing the dtypes within the DataFrame with the dtypes on the SQL table itself.

You probably don't need to manually specify the datatypes in pandas itself but if you do, [here's how](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21197774/assign-pandas-dataframe-column-dtypes).
*Spoiler alert: it is written in the [pandas.Dataframe documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandasdocs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) that only a single dtype must be specified so you will need some loops or manual column work to get different types.*

To solve your problem:

```python
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("connection_string")

df = pd.DataFrame(item_list)
dtypes = {"forretningshændelse": sqlalchemy.types.String(length=8),
     "forretningsområde": sqlalchemy.types.String(40), 
     "forretningsproces": sqlalchemy.types.INTEGER(), 
     "id_namespace": sqlalchemy.types.String(100), 
     "id_lokalId": sqlalchemy.types.String(36),
     "kommunekode": sqlalchemy.types.INTEGER(), 
     "registreringFra": sqlalchemy.types.DateTime()}

with engine.connect() as engine:
    df.to_sql("table_name",if_exists="replace", con=engine, dtype=dtypes)
```

Tip: Avoid using special characters while coding in general, it only makes maintaining code harder at some point :). I assumed you're creating a new sql table and not appending, otherwise types for the table would already be defined.

Happy Coding!

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Tip: There are other languages than English! Everything you are referring to as special characters are predefined in the input data... a 47GB JSON file. Took me long enough to find a way to deal with a file of this size.